# is it ok to use "unstick " when you don't want people removing a plastic trip from its intended places?

Tags: word-usage, word-request

This is a picture of a diaper. It has a small strip on its back. After use, The trip will be used to fasten the diaper for easy disposal.

[image]

Your child often tries to remove or "unstick" it.

is it OK to say "**Please don't unstick it**".

[The oxford dictionary](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/unstuck?q=unstuck) has the adjective "**unstuck**" but it doesn't have the verb "**unstick**"

> come unstuck
>
> ​to become separated from something it was stuck or fastened to
>
> The flap of the envelope had come unstuck.

Comment: The Oxford examples imply coming apart accidentally. You could say to your child "Don't pull it apart."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this example:

when you cut your finger, you put a band aid on it to stop the finger from bleeding. after a while you might want to remove/take off/rip off the band aid, however we never say **unstick** the band aid for some reason.

the strip of sticky plastic in the picture you provided greatly resembles a band aid so I guess it's safe to use:

```
    take off, rip off, pull aprt or remove
```

to convey the desired meaning. (although rip off brings to mind a quick violent action to remove the band aid or strip)I guess you could also use, **loosen** but it kind of sounds awkward as it's usually used for things like screws and so on.

as for **unstick**, Let's look at the definition:

verb
If you unstick something or if it unsticks, it becomes separated from the thing that it was stuck to. (Collins dictionary)

So, we can use **unstick** as well, it would suggest that **we** were the ones sticking the plastic strip on its place, as if it wasn't done in a factory, which is not the case. I guess it would sound a bit weird to use **unstick** in this case. Additionally, according to this Ngram comparing the frequency of, "take off", "remove", and "unstick," **unstick** is extremely less common than the other two. 
[image]

ref: https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/stick (entry 2, look under antonyms)

ref: https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/unstick